# Using map for pose estimation

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, gmapping, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Quite a newbie question, but I can't understand the right way to do things properly.
(I'm using groovy under Ubuntu 12.04).

I want to get a position and orientation estimations of my PR2 robot (simulated or real) in my node.

I have gmapping running that builds me a map and publish a transform between the frame odom_combined and map.
On the other hand, I subscribed to the /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined topic and I get frequent odometry pose estimations. I understand that I could use AMCL for localisation (which provides the amcl_pose topic) but to keep my architecture simple, I just want to use gmapping. I don't use only the odom estimation because of its drift over time.

I also "lookup for transform" between odom and map :

```
(...)
try
{
    nhCall_.getParam("gmapping_node/odom_frame", frameToTransform);
    listener.lookupTransform("/map", frameToTransform, ros::Time(0), transform_base);
}
(...)
```

But how do I use the transform (transform_base) as a pose estimation ? As it is a StampedTransform, I can't directly set it as my pose. When trying to set, field by field the Pose message with the transform data, I end up with the following warning :

```
[ WARN] [1432023038.082861765, 6687.377000000]: MSG to TF: Quaternion Not Properly Normalized
```

and I'm not sure normalizing it by hand is the best solution (the warning still appears when rotating).
So can someone explain me the right way to use a transform for pose estimation ?

Thanks,
Erwan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209482/using-map-for-pose-estimation/) by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on ROS Answers with karma: 697 on 2015-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Forgetting about your mapping and slam setup, the way to get your robot position is to get a transform from your /base_frame to /map (and not /odom to /map, as ideally it should be constant and only changes due to drift errors, check the image in the bottom of [this page](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl)). Once you have that transform, you can obtain the position of your robot using the getOrigin() method, as shown in [this example](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29).

related question [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/39250/getting-the-position-and-the-pose-of-robot-using-tf_listener/).

bonus: if you want to try a very simple SLAM setup, I suggest you try [hector_slam](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam).

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2015-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to point out that, if you are using GMapping, you cannot use AMCL too: GMapping is a SLAM algorithm including localization in itself.

BTW, do you try to normalize the quaternion by normalize() method before create your message? See [tf::Quaternion](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Quaternion.html) documentation.

---

Originally posted by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) with karma: 497 on 2015-05-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2015-05-20**:
Thanks for answering ! To my experience, AMCL and gmapping aren't incompatible, and AMCL requires a map, so a good way to provide this is from gmapping and the poses estimates from both methods aren't writing on the same topic.
I didn't use normalize, I'm gonna give it a try.